# Write to multiple output files using input file line numbers

Tags: perl, file, file-io

Yes I know maybe the title is not very clear. If you have suggestions about changing it, please tell me.

This is my problem:
I have one file (we call it File_1) where there are several lines, each one is a sentence.

For ex:
File_1 content:

```
*Line 1*: I'm very happy today.
*Line 2*: We're going to the cinema.
*Line 3*: I'll write on stackoverflow today!
```

And so on..

My question is, how can I create several files from the content of each line? 
So for ex. file_1 will be splitted into:

```
*Line_1_content.txt* : I'm very happy today.
*Line_2_content.txt* : We're going to the cinema.
```

And so on...

I don't know how to do, really. I've never faced this kind of problem. 
I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Are those bits "*Line_1_content.txt*" (and "*Line 1*") part of the files, or just explanation?

Comment: what exactly is the question? How to track the line number? You may use http://perldoc.perl.org/FileHandle.html where you have the input_line_number which tracks the line number. Then you have just to create for each line a file in your while loop?. Except that it is very easy to read and write files in perl.

Comment: The question is how to create from a single file, several files with the content of each line of the single file.

Comment: Do you really need to put each line into a separate file? Why? That seems a terribly inefficient way to represent your data. Or can multiple lines end up in the same file? How?

Comment: when I want to copy a line in another file I write print OUT $line.. OUT can correspond to "text1.txt". But in this case OUT will change for  every $line.. How can automatically modify the name of the OUT file everytime?

Comment: Yes @reinierpost, I need several files because after I need to handle the content of each one separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly the question something line:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open(my $fh, '<', 'example.txt');
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
  open(my $line_fh, '>', "line_${.}_file.txt");
  print $line_fh $line;
  close($line_fh);
}
close($fh);
```

Should do what you want.

(Although doing this maybe doesn't make a lot of sense like the comments point out)

Comment: You can use $. to get the number of the current line.

Comment: Good point, I knew that exists but I was too lazy to check which one was the variable that contains it :D

Comment: ok thank you. So I can replace the syntax (OUT, ">", "line_${current_line}_file.txt") with the one you've written. I would like to learn more about directories, file handle on perl... I know there's official documentation but is there a easier tutorial online?

Comment: There is a lot of info out there about Perl but sadly you can find many old and bad examples about how to do things :( I think http://perlmaven.com/perl-tutorial is a good resource. There is the search engine http://search.perlhacks.com/ that picks results only from trusted Perl sites (but I haven't used it too much)

Answer (score 3):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

while ( <> ) {
    open my $fh, '>', "${.}.txt";
    print $fh $_;
}
```

`$.` corresponds to the number of the current line.

You call this program like this: `perl prog.pl your_file`

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a program :-)

```
perl -ne 'open my $fh, ">", "Line_${.}_content.txt"; print $fh $_"' your_file_here
```

Or, perhaps,

```
perl -pe 'open my $fh, ">", "Line_${.}_content.txt"; select $fh' your_file_here
```